# AutoGen 2.0 Where are my workflows saved?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, autogen

I'm working in windows, with Microconda and Microsoft AutoGen 2.0.  I got AutoGen up and running, and have started creating skills.

I want to understand where my work (skills, agents, workflows) is stored, so that I can ensure it's backed up, etc. so I don't lose it.

And along the same lines, can I control where I want my work stored, so that I can have it together with all my other various dev projects.  I'm just not seeing any options in the tool or the documentation.

Comment: Responding on the vote to close my question... I can't think of what more detail is needed here.  Where does this program store its data - it's a simple ask.  Please let me know what information is missing in order for this question to be understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AutoGen Studio, your work (skills, agents, workflows) is saved in a `database.sqlite` file. This file is crucial for backing up and ensuring you don't lose your work (See FAQS: https://microsoft.github.io/autogen/blog/2023/12/01/AutoGenStudio/).

For managing and resetting your development environment, such as performing a factory reset, deleting the `database.sqlite file` effectively clears all your configurations and data, allowing you to start over.

This process is demonstrated in a video tutorial at https://youtu.be/X6pP9zyfkyY?t=353, where it's used to reset the entire conversation history with an agent.